# angular-leaflet-directive doesn't update markers when calling a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm very new to Angular and Leaflet.

I followed the example of iH8 from this question: [how make ng-model="search" have influence on leaflet directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757491/how-make-ng-model-search-have-influence-on-leaflet-directive)

If this event is fired

```
function receiveMessage(event){
$scope.geojson.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, 'name', 'some Value');
}
```

from another tab or frame with postMessage:

```
receiver.postMessage('value', 'URL')
```

the view changes and everything works fine. If I call this function locally or any other function with

```
$scope.geojson.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, 'name', 'some Value');
```

nothing changes. Can someone explain me why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be an issue with the event occurring outside of the digest cycle; check out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply